# Oracle query to concat a column data having two rows into one

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an Oracle column with "Long" datatype, as the column has the 4000 chars limit, we tend to insert data into two rows or more than that, now we want to display 2 rows of data into one, I tried but there are some of the other error like char to long and so on, could you please help.

```
Id, Series, Serialized

1       1        abc
1       1        def
3       2        gdf

Id, Series

1       1        
1       1        
3       2        

Output

Id, Series, Serialized
1       1        abcdef
3       2        gdf

Here's the table scripts

 CREATE TABLE "LOGMESSAGE" 
   (    "ID" VARCHAR2(36 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "SERIALIZEDMESSAGE" LONG, 
    "SERIES" NUMBER(10,0)
   ) 
   
    CREATE TABLE "LOGENTRY" 
   (    "ID" VARCHAR2(36 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE
   ) 
   
    insert into "LOGMESSAGE" values(
   'd8dcd593-af52-425a-8bf2-d93f78a601c6','{"name":"miogetadapter001.xml","type":"miogetadapterresponse","id":"56e125af-4202-44cb-bf90-58df03776793","time":"2021-10-05T06:27:04.8595987Z","source":"miochannelsource","adapter":"miotestadapter","channel":"miotestchannel","original":"<RESTTestResponse TestTimestamp=\"2021/10/05 11:57:05\">\r\n  <Name>miotestadapter</Name>\r\n  <IsActive>true</IsActive>\r\n  <Description>Added during MIO install for confirmation test.  Version=3.0.0.0</Description>\r\n  <type>ChannelAdapterConfiguration</type>\r\n  <AdapterConfigurationTypeName>FileAdapterConfiguration</AdapterConfigurationTypeName>\r\n  <AdapterType>FileAdapter</AdapterType>\r\n  <AdapterVersion>1</AdapterVersion>\r\n  <AdapterKind>default</AdapterKind>\r\n  <ContentFormat>Xml</ContentFormat>\r\n  <ChannelSourceName>miochannelsource</ChannelSourceName>\r\n  <MessageChannelName>miotestchannel</MessageChannelName>\r\n  <MomConnectionName></MomConnectionName>\r\n  <OutboundNameFormat>{messagename}</OutboundNameFormat>\r\n  <InboundNameFormat>{messagename}</InboundNameFormat>\r\n  <DoNotSend>false</DoNotSend>\r\n  <DoNotSendOutbound>false</DoNotSendOutbound>\r\n  <ShutdownMaxTime>15</ShutdownMaxTime>\r\n  <IsXml>true</IsXml>\r\n  <WakeUpInterval>-1</WakeUpInterval>\r\n  <UserName></UserName>\r\n  <Password></Password>\r\n  <DomainName></DomainName>\r\n  <VerifyUnique>true</VerifyUnique>\r\n  <UniqueIncludesTimestamp>true</UniqueIncludesTimestamp>\r\n  <UniqueCacheExpiration>0</UniqueCacheExpiration>\r\n  <ClearOriginalContents>true</ClearOriginalContents>\r\n  <BufferSettings>\r\n    <Description></Description>\r\n    <Kind>Persistent</Kind>\r\n    <ConnectionName></ConnectionName>\r\n    <ConnectionString>folder name=%AppData%</ConnectionString>\r\n    <Interval>2000</Interval>\r\n    <Expiration>-1</Expiration>\r\n    <MaxCount>-1</MaxCount>\r\n  </BufferSettings>\r\n  <InProcessExpiration>120</InProcessExpiration>\r\n  <InboundFilters />\r\n  <OutboundFilters />\r\n  <OutboundFailPlugin>LogAndDiscard</OutboundFailPlugin>\r\n  <OutboundFailConfiguration>LogAndDiscard</OutboundFailConfiguration>\r\n  <OutboundRetryInterval>15000</OutboundRetryInterval>\r\n  <OutboundMaxRetries>5</OutboundMaxRetries>\r\n  <SendMessageMaxRetries>10</SendMessageMaxRetries>\r\n  <SendMessageRetryInterval>10000</SendMessageRetryInterval>\r\n  <InboundUri>C:\\Program Files\\Opcenter Connect MOM\\Channel Adapter Host\\inbound</InboundUri>\r\n  <OutboundUri>C:\\Program Files\\Opcenter Connect MOM\\Channel Adapter Host\\outbound</OutboundUri>\r\n  <ErrorUri></ErrorUri>\r\n  <InboundDriveToMap></InboundDriveToMap>\r\n  <InboundFilenameFilter>*.*</InboundFilenameFilter>\r\n  <OutboundDriveToMap></OutboundDriveToMap>\r\n  <MaxReadRetries>10</MaxReadRetries>\r\n  <RetryDelay>15000</RetryDelay>\r\n  <DeleteInterval>15</DeleteInterval>\r\n  <EncodingName>UTF-8</EncodingName>\r\n</RESTTestResponse>","contents":"<RESTTestResponse TestTimestamp=\"2021/10/05 11:57:05\">\r\n  <Name>miotestadapter</Name>\r\n  <IsActive>true</IsActive>\r\n  <Description>Added during MIO install for confirmation test.  Version=3.0.0.0</Description>\r\n  <type>ChannelAdapterConfiguration</type>\r\n  <AdapterConfigurationTypeName>FileAdapterConfiguration</AdapterConfigurationTypeName>\r\n  <AdapterType>FileAdapter</AdapterType>\r\n  <AdapterVersion>1</AdapterVersion>\r\n  <AdapterKind>default</AdapterKind>\r\n  <ContentFormat>Xml</ContentFormat>\r\n  <ChannelSourceName>miochannelsource</ChannelSourceName>\r\n  <MessageChannelName>miotestchannel</MessageChannelName>\r\n  <MomConnectionName></MomConnectionName>\r\n  <OutboundNameFormat>{messagename}</OutboundNameFormat>\r\n  <InboundNameFormat>{messagename}</InboundNameFormat>\r\n  <DoNotSend>false</DoNotSend>\r\n  <DoNotSendOutbound>false</DoNotSendOutbound>\r\n  <ShutdownMaxTime>15</ShutdownMaxTime>\r\n  <IsXml>true</IsXml>\r\n  <WakeUpInterval>-1</WakeUpInterval>\r\n  <UserName></UserName>\r\n  <Password></Password>\r\n  <DomainName></DomainName>\r\n  <VerifyUnique>true</VerifyUniqu',
   0)
   
   insert into "LOGMESSAGE" values(
   'd8dcd593-af52-425a-8bf2-d93f78a601c6','e>\r\n  <UniqueIncludesTimestamp>true</UniqueIncludesTimestamp>\r\n  <UniqueCacheExpiration>0</UniqueCacheExpiration>\r\n  <ClearOriginalContents>true</ClearOriginalContents>\r\n  <BufferSettings>\r\n    <Description></Description>\r\n    <Kind>Persistent</Kind>\r\n    <ConnectionName></ConnectionName>\r\n    <ConnectionString>folder name=%AppData%</ConnectionString>\r\n    <Interval>2000</Interval>\r\n    <Expiration>-1</Expiration>\r\n    <MaxCount>-1</MaxCount>\r\n  </BufferSettings>\r\n  <InProcessExpiration>120</InProcessExpiration>\r\n  <InboundFilters />\r\n  <OutboundFilters />\r\n  <OutboundFailPlugin>LogAndDiscard</OutboundFailPlugin>\r\n  <OutboundFailConfiguration>LogAndDiscard</OutboundFailConfiguration>\r\n  <OutboundRetryInterval>15000</OutboundRetryInterval>\r\n  <OutboundMaxRetries>5</OutboundMaxRetries>\r\n  <SendMessageMaxRetries>10</SendMessageMaxRetries>\r\n  <SendMessageRetryInterval>10000</SendMessageRetryInterval>\r\n  <InboundUri>C:\\Program Files\\Opcenter Connect MOM\\Channel Adapter Host\\inbound</InboundUri>\r\n  <OutboundUri>C:\\Program Files\\Opcenter Connect MOM\\Channel Adapter Host\\outbound</OutboundUri>\r\n  <ErrorUri></ErrorUri>\r\n  <InboundDriveToMap></InboundDriveToMap>\r\n  <InboundFilenameFilter>*.*</InboundFilenameFilter>\r\n  <OutboundDriveToMap></OutboundDriveToMap>\r\n  <MaxReadRetries>10</MaxReadRetries>\r\n  <RetryDelay>15000</RetryDelay>\r\n  <DeleteInterval>15</DeleteInterval>\r\n  <EncodingName>UTF-8</EncodingName>\r\n</RESTTestResponse>","empty":false,"contentsformat":"Xml","contentshash":"64882DB2ED9382F3075C94A0657C3034","hash":"135D1EEE963EC392868AF2AFF7DE5711","priority":1,"outbound":true,"request":false,"response":true,"requestid":"06da6532-bfd0-4a77-9637-b4da6f48b23a","events":[],"attributes":{"filename":"miogetadapter001.xml","restcommand":"/api/channeladapters","httpverb":"GET","querystring":"name=miotestadapter"},"tagdata":"","adaptertagdata":{"properties":"{\r\n  \"encoding\": \"UTF-8\",\r\n  \"source\": \"miochannelsource\",\r\n  \"adapter\": \"miotestadapter\",\r\n  \"directory\": \"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Opcenter Connect MOM\\\\Channel Adapter Host\\\\inbound\"\r\n}"},"status":"","correlationid":"","maxretrycount":10,"retrycount":0,"automapped":false,"express":false,"inhibitEvent":false,"eventonly":false,"eventttl":0,"check":{"timestamp":"2021-10-05T06:27:04.8626024Z","stages":[{"name":"Created","machineName":"VM-VDIP49-03","timestamp":"2021-10-05T06:27:04.8626024Z","time":0,"duration":0},{"name":"Adapter Host Added","machineName":"VM-VDIP49-03","timestamp":"2021-10-05T06:27:04.8645993Z","time":1,"duration":1},{"name":"Adapter Host Dispatch","machineName":"VM-VDIP49-03","timestamp":"2021-10-05T06:27:04.869603Z","time":7,"duration":6,"dispatcher":"BrokerBalanced"},{"name":"Broker Received","machineName":"VM-VDIP49-03","timestamp":"2021-10-05T06:27:04.8905926Z","time":27,"duration":20},{"name":"Broker Added","machineName":"VM-VDIP49-03","timestamp":"2021-10-05T06:27:04.8925959Z","time":29,"duration":2},{"name":"Broker Dispatch","machineName":"VM-VDIP49-03","timestamp":"2021-10-05T06:27:04.9285978Z","time":65,"duration":36,"availThreads":24,"dispatcher":"fifowithpredecessors"},{"name":"Broker Added","machineName":"VM-VDIP49-03","timestamp":"2021-10-05T06:27:05.0966056Z","time":234,"duration":169},{"name":"Broker Dispatch","machineName":"VM-VDIP49-03","timestamp":"2021-10-05T06:27:05.1066034Z","time":244,"duration":10,"availThreads":24,"dispatcher":"fifowithpredecessors"},{"name":"Adapter Host Received","machineName":"VM-VDIP49-03","timestamp":"2021-10-05T06:27:05.1216049Z","time":259,"duration":15},{"name":"Adapter Host Send","machineName":"VM-VDIP49-03","timestamp":"2021-10-05T06:27:05.1486105Z","time":286,"duration":27}]}}',
   1)

   
   insert into "LOGENTRY"
   values ('d8dcd593-af52-425a-8bf2-d93f78a601c6')

**Tried Query**
 SELECT M.Id,RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,M.SerializedMessage,',').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY M.SerializedMessage).GetClobVal(),',') AS LIST1,M.Series
         from LOGENTRY E INNER JOIN LOGMESSAGE M ON E.Id = M.Id group by M.Id,M.series;

**Error**
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got LONG
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
```

Comment: Did you consider to use `CLOB` and store the data in *one row*?

Comment: Please edit the question and show all error?

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I can't use clob as a table column because of some restriction but I need to use it in query

Comment: @OldProgrammer I don't have the error just consider I don't know how to write queries especially the complex ones.

Comment: So if there is no error is the problem that you get no results back?  I doubt that you can to listagg on a long

Comment: Where is the 4000 character restriction coming from? LONG and CLOB data types don't have that restriction naturally.

Comment: Since Oracle 12c you may have aligned SQL and PL/SQL `varchar2` datatypes (both of the same 32k limit) with [`max_string_size`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-D424D23B-0933-425F-BC69-9C0E6724693C.htm) parameter. If it is not enough it would be much better to store the value in a single row as `clob` since it hat less restrictions on operations and support up to 2^64-1 bytes of data

Comment: @OldProgrammer My colleague reverted to old changes because of the error, I need to wait for him till tomorrow for you to post the error, meanwhile can't I expect a simple query where two rows are merged into one with clob or larger field.

Comment: @astentx thanks, I'm awaiting for someone to post a query as a solution.

Comment: There isn't an easy way to do what you're asking in SQL; options with the LONG datatype in particular are very limited. Still not sure where your limitation is coming from, and why you can't store everything in the same row - LONG or CLOB - to begin with.

Comment: @pmdba I have edited my question, you can try and see

Comment: @OldProgrammer You got everything as requested in the question

Answer (score 0):

The long datatype by itself has lots of restrictions and is very difficult to work with in general. There's a reason why it's deprecated and you're just giving yourself extra work, finding ways around it, instead of using clobs.

But to answer your question, this is, I think, probably what you wanted:

```
SELECT listagg(a.linetext, '') within group (order by rownum)
FROM
(
    SELECT 'a' linetext from dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a' linetext from dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2' linetext from dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b' linetext from dual
) a
```

Replace the subquery with a query of your table and it will concat your results, which you get in separate lines.

Comment: It's not working, same error => ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got LONG
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Comment: @Mysterious288 Make sure the columns in each row have the same datatypes. Also attempt to convert them to varchar2 with CAST or CONVERT, or convert them to a CLOB with .getClobVal()

Comment: Can you give me an example, for me it's not working

Comment: You can't use `CAST`.  From the Oracle documentation "CAST does not support LONG, LONG RAW, or the Oracle-supplied types"

Comment: @Del What's the alternative ??